# exporting after promise finishes

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like to export a class which initial state depends on a value returned from a `Promise` in another module i cannot modify.

Here's the code:

```
let e = true;

APromiseFromAnotherModule()
  .then(value => return value;);

export default class E {
  constructor() {
    if (e) {
      //...
    } else {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried with `async/await` encapsulating the `Promise` into an async function like this:

```
let e = true;

getInitialValue = async () => {
  return await APromiseFromAnotherModule()
    .then(value => e = value;);
};

e = getInitialValue();

export default class E {
  constructor() {
    if (e) {
      //...
    } else {
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't make sense because that one is an `async` function so obviously it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: As far as i know export is synchronously. (but you could change properties of it async. And a constructor is also sync.

Comment: You are assigning `e` twice here, why? Once in the return from the async and then the setting to the return of `getInitialValue()`

Comment: +1, export is synchronous. Besides, it's a really bad practice to export an instance of the class. You should export the class and delegate the async stuff to the instantiation, which should happen in the file where the class is imported

Comment: @wmash yes you are right, but anyway it doesn't work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

module exports are done synchronously.  So, they cannot depend upon the results of an asynchronous operation.

And, `await` only works inside a function.  It doesn't actually block the containing function (the containing function returns a promise) so that won't help you make an async operation into a synchronous one either.

The usual ways to deal with a module that uses some async code in its setup is to either export a promise and have the calling code use `.then()` on the promise or to initialize the module with a constructor function that returns a promise.

The code is only pseudo code so it's hard to tell exactly what your real problem is to show you specific code for your situation.

As an example.  If you want to export a `class` definition, but don't want the class definition used until some async code has completed, you can do something like this:

```
// do async initialization and keep promise
let e;
const p = APromiseFromAnotherModule().then(val => e = val);

class E {
    constructor() {
        if (e) {
            //...
        } else {
            //...
        }
    }
};

// export constructor function
export default function() {
   return p.then(e => {
       // after async initialization is done, resolve with class E
       return E;
   });
}
```

The caller could then use it like this:

```
import init from 'myModule';
init().then(E => {
   // put code here that uses E
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
   // handle error here
});
```

This solves several issues:

1. Asynchronous initialization is started immediately upon module loading.
2. class E is not made available to the caller until the async initialization is done so it can't be used until its ready
3. The same `class E` is used for all users of the module
4. The async initialization is cached so it's only done once

---

**Edit in 2023.** Modern nodejs versions when using ESM modules have top level `await` so it is possible to `await` an asynchronous result before your exports.

Comment: If the const p and Class E is moved inside the default function export then it wont be cached right?

Comment: @ShyamBabu - Correct.  It won't be cached and you will be creating a new E for every loading of that module.  That's why I moved it outside.  FYI, we could help a lot more specifically if we saw the real code.

Comment: Agreed but then APromiseFromAnotherModule will also cache along with the class?

Comment: @ShyamBabu - It all depends upon what you want cached.  Your design.

Comment: Will depend on OP need i suppose. Thank you for clarifying my doubt.:)

Comment: @ShyamBabu - The OP was already trying to cache the promise in their initial design which is why I assumed it should be cached, but it's totally up the design.   Usually a module initialization is meant to be done once and then shared.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that [@jfriend00's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49074172/5943840) works fine, but in my case, there is not just one block of code that depends on the foreign async function's completion.

In my app, configuration loading is asynchronous, so the server must wait for the configs to load before starting. Since there are other files (like routes) that compose the server that *also* need access to the configs, I would have to reluctantly call `.then()` in each other file.

Here is how I was able to do it with `require` statements instead of `export`.

### config.js

Module that can be required by other modules in order to gain access to the global configs.

```js
module.exports.loadAllConfigs = async () => {
  const appConfigs = await AsyncConfigLibrary.load();
  module.exports.CONFIG = appConfigs;
};
```

### server.js

Main file for Node application that makes use of other modules that require access to global configs.

```js
const { loadAllConfigs } = require('./modules/config');

loadAllConfigs()
  .then(() => {
    const { CONFIG } = require('./modules/config');

    /* import modules */
    const auth = require('./modules/auth');
};
```

### auth.js

Module used by `server.js` that requires access to configs.

```js
const { CONFIG } = require('./config');
const cookieSecret = CONFIG.secretItem;
```

Therefore, as long as the `CONFIG` property is set in `config.js` before any of the other modules attempt to access it, that is, before the modules are `require`'d, then the single `.then()` in `server.js` is sufficient.